# crontab with sudo python script

Tags: python, cron, sudo

Alright, I've found something. Not sure how to tackle it. I've seen that this is a common error that comes up in google. The error seems to have something to do with the environment variables or something. Not sure how to handle this:

This is the code and it's the part where subprocess is called that leads to the error:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import subprocess
import re
import sys
import time
import datetime
import gspread

# ===========================================================================
# Google Account Details
# ===========================================================================

# Account details for google docs
email       = 'my_email@gmail.com'
password    = 'my_password'
spreadsheet = 'my_spreadsheet'

# ===========================================================================
# Example Code
# ===========================================================================


# Login with your Google account
try:
  gc = gspread.login(email, password)
except:
  print "Unable to log in.  Check your email address/password"
  sys.exit()

# Open a worksheet from your spreadsheet using the filename
try:
  worksheet = gc.open(spreadsheet).sheet1
  # Alternatively, open a spreadsheet using the spreadsheet's key
  # worksheet = gc.open_by_key('0BmgG6nO_6dprdS1MN3d3MkdPa142WFRrdnRRUWl1UFE')
except:
  print "Unable to open the spreadsheet.  Check your filename: %s" % spreadsheet
  sys.exit()

# Continuously append data
while(True):
  # Run the DHT program to get the humidity and temperature readings!

  output = subprocess.check_output(["./Adafruit_DHT", "2302", "17"]);
  print output
  matches = re.search("Temp =\s+([0-9.]+)", output)
  if (not matches):
        time.sleep(3)
        continue
  temp1 = float(matches.group(1))
  temp = temp1*9/5+32 # added the extra step to converto to fahrenheit

  # search for humidity printout
  matches = re.search("Hum =\s+([0-9.]+)", output)
  if (not matches):
       time.sleep(3)
       continue
  humidity = float(matches.group(1))

  print "Temperature: %.1f F" % temp
  print "Humidity:    %.1f %%" % humidity

  # Append the data in the spreadsheet, including a timestamp
  try:
    values = [datetime.datetime.now(), temp, humidity]
    worksheet.append_row(values)
  except:
    print "Unable to append data.  Check your connection?"
    sys.exit()

  # Wait 30 seconds before continuing or just exit
  print "Wrote a row to %s" % spreadsheet
#  time.sleep(60)
  sys.exit()
```

that's basically it. It works fine using 'sudo python script.py' as long as the Adafruit_DHT program is in the same directory.

Here's the error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Adafruit/dht/Ada_temp.py", line 44, in <module>
    output = subprocess.check_output(["./home/pi/Adafruit/dht/Adafruit_DHT", "2302", "17"]);
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 537, in check_output
    process = Popen(stdout=PIPE, *popenargs, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1259, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I've tried adding the full path of the c program (Adafruit_DHT), to no avail...

Comment: You should see errors in `/var/log/syslog`. Is there any?

Comment: Does your script not run at all, or it runs but does not write to the google spreadsheet?

Comment: What user is cron running as?  Is it in sudoers?  Could you wrap the python script in a bash script that calls sudo?

Comment: Not much in syslog, the same message as another cron that works. The script works fine, when typed in with sudo (the cron is run as user root). I will have to research doing the bash script...

Comment: `crontab` has its own environment. Try specifying the absolute path to python. Also, don't call `sudo` within crontab. If you must run it as root, call the script normally from within `sudo crontab`

Comment: what about the permissions of the file ? chmod 777 ?

Comment: yeah, i'm trying to avoid the good 'ol chmod 777...

Comment: though maybe 777 temporarily just to test it...

Comment: no, wait, i thought it was the access to the gpio that requires sudo, so i don't think chmod 777ing the script will help anyway...

Answer (score 0):

Locate the problem.

1. Does the script run at all?
   Do something trivial in the first line of the script to see that it actually gets executed from **cron** (e.g.: write to a file in /tmp).
2. Once you managed to run it, look for other problems. Cron can be set up to send the a mail with the output of the script. One obvious thing I see is: `./Adafruit_DHT`, relative path is used, that's a bad sign, the cron script is probably not executed in the directory you think it does. Fix it (= use absolute path).

Comment: well, the script runs beautifully, when I type 'sudo python script.py' in the command line (i'm ssh'd in). It prints the output to the screen, i can watch the google spreadsheet create a new row, the bam! the data is in there. I just can't seem to get it to run in crontab and now i've a separate bash script calling up from /etc/init.d and that doesn't work either. funny thing though, using /etc/init.d/script start, it starts the python script but not in the background. I was using the noip2 init.d script example tailored to my python script.

Comment: I've had it running from my /home/pi directory and from /usr/local/bin directory (with the Adafruit_DHT c program in there too). It seems to only run if I manually type the command. It's just refusing to do it in the background via crontab or /etc/init.d... :(

Comment: Don't know what to say. It seems like you either haven't read my answer or simply ignored it.

Comment: ok, so in answering the first part of your answer 1 with "the script runs beautifully" I figured that was enough. But looking at that some more, maybe you understand that, but mean "does it run while activated in crontab?" hmmm... well, I've looked in the /var/log/syslog and can see that an instance is created with some info that is pretty much the same as another script I have running (successfully, but without sudo) in crontab. It's just that nothing is generated. I guess I'll have to reanalyze your steps 1 and 2 and try to figure out what you mean and how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
output = subprocess.check_output(["PATH_TO_Adafruit_DHT/Adafruit_DHT", "2302", "17"]);
```

Oh and change your cron line to:
/usr/bin/python /home/pi/myscript.py

Comment: As long has the script has a proper `#!` line, it's not necessary to invoke it via `/usr/bin/python` explicitly.

Comment: From what I've experienced in the past it doesn't always work with `#!`. Better safe than sorry.